# "raw_reaction_remove" not removing roles why?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

*My raw reaction add is working just fine but why im getting this error on remove ?*

CODE:

```
@commands.Cog.listener() 
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):

    msgID = 754487460142121070
    user = payload.user_id
    member = payload.user_id

    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, bot1.guilds)
    
    canarinho = get(member.guild.roles, name="Canarinho")

    if not payload.guild_id:
        return

    if payload is not None:
        if payload.message_id == msgID:
            if str(payload.emoji) == ":canarinho:":
                await member.remove_roles(canarinho)
```

Error:

```
    canarinho = get(member.guild.roles, name="Canarinho")
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally repeated a line.

```
 member = payload.user_id
```

It should be

```
member = payload.member
```